# Insert php snippet after checking correct password

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, shortcode, password-protection

I have a Wordpress page where a user can book language classes. There are different booking options, so I built the page in a way that the booking form charges dinamically from URL. The DOM charges 16 different shortcodes but in front-end it's only displayed the one that user enters in the URL by setting some parameters. The only problem about this is that the page takes a lot of time to charge and display the form.

I'm trying to figure out a way to charge only one shortcode and only set dinamically the value that differs between all shortcodes. After some researching (as my PHP knowledge is limited), I tried this code, and it worked:

```
function php_insert() {
    if( is_page( 645 ) ) {
            $awQueryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            parse_str($awQueryString, $awQueryStringParams);
            $language = $awQueryStringParams['lang'];
            $pack = $awQueryStringParams['pack'];
            if (empty($awQueryString)) {
                echo 'The URL entered is invalid. Please refresh the page with the correct URL or contact the web admin.';
            } 
            else if ($language == 'english') {
                if ($pack == '5') {
                    echo do_shortcode('[ameliacatalog package=13]');
                }
                if ($pack == '10') {
                    echo do_shortcode('[ameliacatalog package=14]');
                }
                if ($pack == '25') {
                    echo do_shortcode('[ameliacatalog package=15]');
                }
            } 
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'php_insert');
```

The problem now is that this page is protected by password, and this snippet charges the code at the top of the page and it doesn't wait to check that the password is correct.

I don't know if this is the best way to do this workaround. Also don't know how can I do to solve the password check and location problem.

I hope I have explained everything well.

Thanks

Comment: _“and this snippet charges the code at the top of the page”_ - well that’s because you used the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook for this, which is really not the right place for stuff like this, not at all. It’s not actually a _script_ file, is it? No, you want to output content in the body area of the page somewhere. So check if the theme you are using provides any hooks you could use specifically in the place where you want the output to appear. If not, hooking into the `the_content` filter might also be a way to add this to the main page content.

Comment: Thank you CBroe. I apologize, cause as I said, my level of PHP is very basic and that piece of code is made from another similar found in this forum. I get your point, but even changing the hook or creating a new custom one in my child theme, it always appears ignoring the password protected page form. I don't know how to add a condition to check the authentication or where to hook the code so that it appears only when the password form is filled correctly.